# How to calculate the weights for Discrete Laplacian Operator?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, laplacian

I am following this paper [enter link description here](https://mathematicians.korea.ac.kr/cfdkim/wp-content/uploads/sites/15/2023/06/ISOTROPIC_FDM.pdf) step by step and want to build an isotropic Laplacian kernel. As shown in the following figure, I can understand until using Taylor to expand the 2D discrete Laplacian operator, but in step (12), the author multiplied this Laplace equation by the weights of **"w"** and **"(1-w)"**, which is exactly what I don't understand. I know that the distance between the diagonal and the center is the square root of 2, so why not 1/(h ^ 2) and 1/2 (h ^ 2) as the weights? What is the difference between these two? And why does the author take 4/5 as the value of w?
I would be appreciated for any explanations or resources.[image]

Answer (score 1):

The author has derived two different discrete Laplacians:  one based on the four adjacent points, and another based on the four "corners."  It looks you have two choices and you may wonder which is better.  However, the author is saying "why choose?"  You could take 10% of the first choice plus 90% of the second.  Or, more generally, $w$ of the first and $1-w$ of the second.  Introducing $w$ gives you one degree of freedom to play with in your discrete Laplacian formula.  If you were lucky, you might find a value of $w$ that eliminates the $O(h^2)$ term, producing a more accurate approximation.  Unfortunately, that is not possible in this case, but what is possible is to eliminate the anisotropic part of the $O(h^2)$ term.  This, at least, makes dominant part of the error term invariant under rotations.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But could you please further explain what the “eliminate the anisotropic part of the O(h^2)” stands for?  And, if we change the weight ratio between the original kernel and the kernel rotated 45 degrees, i.e. 1/h^2 and 1/2(h^2), wouldn't that make it not strictly a laplacian operator? Or does it just have to look like a second derivative?

Comment: Sure.  The $O(h^2)$ part of the error in the fourth line of (12) has $\Delta^2 u$ and $u_{xxyy}$ terms.  If you could eliminate both, the error would be $O(h^3)$.  You can't eliminate both, but by setting $u = 4/5$ you can eliminate the $u_{xxyy}$ term.  Why bother?  Because the Laplacian itself is isotropic (i.e., it doesn't change if you rotate the coordinate system $(x,y)$) so it would be nice if the discrete approximation to it had this property as well.  By setting $u=4/5$ the error is approximately isotropic because anisotropic terms occur only in at order $h^3$ and higher.

Comment: The $1/h^2$ factor converts from differences to an approximation to the Laplacian in the same way that a $1/h$ factor converts $u_{i+1}-u_i$ from a difference to an approximation of the derivative.  The $1/(2h^2)$ factor does the same thing on a grid with spacing $\sqrt{2}h$.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, I've reviewed some knowledge about big O notation. But after that, there are still many things I don't understand. Firstly, in step (12), the author changed item （uₓₓₓₓ + 12(1-ω)/(2-ω)uₓₓᵧᵧ + uᵧᵧᵧᵧ ） to item （∆²u + (8-10ω)/(2-ω)uₓₓᵧᵧ ）, and I don't know how this was achieved. The author seems to have just summed uₓₓₓₓand uᵧᵧᵧᵧ into ∆²u, right? But how did they get the (8-10ω)/(2-ω) term? And later on, why could the author just omitted the whole item h²/12（∆²u + 0）?

Comment: One more question, you say that there is anisotropic part in order h³ Is it because there are mixed partial derivatives here? I just can't get the intuition to connect the anisotropic, isotropic and the order of Taylor series.

Comment: $\Delta u = u_{xx} + u_{yy}$ so $\Delta^2 u = u_{xxxx} + 2 u_{xxyy} + u_{yyyy}$, not $u_{xxxx} + u_{yyyy}$.  The author didn't *omit* $h^2/12\; (\Delta^2 u + 0)$, but *absorbed* it into the $O(h^2)$ term in the final line of (12).  Saying $u_{xxyy}$ is anisotropic really means that the operator $D_{xxyy}$ is anisotropic.  An operator is isotropic when applying it to an isotropic function always yields an isotropic function.  Thus we can show $D_{xxyy}$ is anisotropic by letting $u(x,y) = \exp(-(x^2+y^2)) = \exp(-r^2)$ and showing $u_{xxyy}$ isn't a function of $r$.

Comment: You say that the author absorbed that term in O(h²), does that mean the author reduced the quadratic approximation to the linear approximation? If so, isn't the part of uₓₓᵧᵧ are still included in ∆²u ? Did we ignore that part of the error? Or does it not matter if uₓₓᵧᵧ is merged into the nth derivative of the Taylor series, as long as it does not appear in the (x-a) term?

Comment: Thanks again! You're the only person I've been able to find online who's willing to answer this question in detail. My current understanding is that since we cannot have laplace filter rotational invariant in a pixel grid, we approximate isotropic by multiplying the values in the diagonal direction by a weight to change them from h as square root of 2 to h as 1. But the reason we have other versions of weights simply depends on whether we want to keep more values in the adjacent direction or the diagonal direction. Am I reading this correctly?